# Intellij Play and Scala breakpoint issues

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am having some problems with the IntelliJ IDE where it does not stop at breakpoints.

I am running an SBT application with Play 2 framework.

It doesn't matter if I am in an async block or not, the breakpoint doesn't show a "v" inside the red circle and doesn't stop at that breakpoint.

The code reaches that position because I am using a simple print command that I see in the logs.

I tired with run configuration of Play2.

I also tried running the SBT from console and connecting to it with remote debugging.

None of them worked

just to make things clear i tried restarting intellij and the computer (OSX operating system)

This is a real problem. Any ideas?

Comment: in sbt file. fork in run := true -> false solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try execute "sbt compile" and then run your project on debug mode.